# Using kafka as a database using dotnet client

Tags: apache-kafka

I've been looking at using kafka as a database (something i've read is a legitimate use case) from a dotnet app using the Confluent.Kafka client library.

Given a compacted log topic I want to be able to read from offset 0 each time the app starts and cache the results locally. Then consume subsequent messages to update the local cache.

The following consumer config works but I'm unsure if it is correct to set up a Consumer in this way.

```
var config = new ConsumerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "localhost:29092",
    GroupId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    EnableAutoCommit = false
};
```

In order for there to by multiple instances of the app running I've set the GroupId to a Guid to ensure that each new instance will get all the messages.

In order to always read from offset 0 I've set EnableAutoCommit to false and I'm not manually Committing in order to not update the offset. The dotnet client library doesn't appear to have the option to read from beginning.

Is the broker going to cope with the app repeatedly creating new GroupIds?

Is never committing an ok thing to do?

Am I attempting to do something that I shouldn't?

Comment: FWIW, another route to consider is ksqlDB and making calls to it using its REST API from your dotnet app

Comment: What i like about the above is that i've got the initial populate of the local cache plus any updates to it all in one place. No need to poll then update or invalidate then repopulate the cache. The key question that I've not been able to answer yet is: is the broker going to handle thousands of groupIds? I now kafka is all about scalability but it feels like the wrong thing to do. Should groupIds be static and limited in number or is using a Guid as the groupId for each new instance of the app acceptable.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, sorry. But do have a look at ksqlDB and specifically pull queries - it builds and maintains your local cache directly from Kafka, you just query it. https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/tutorials/materialized/